# How do i dynamically import changing feed links within a feed

Tags: 8, feeds

I am uncertain how to approach this.

I have a feed with housing cases that is changing constantly. The feed consists of a case number and a feed link to that particular house. Each house has so much information that it has its own feed. Over time, more will be added and these feed links will change.

For each of these feed links, I want to create a single node. My issue is that I don't really see a solution on how to create these dynamic feeds from the one "main" feed.

It's going to be about 75-150 feeds within the "main" feed. So I have this list of changing feed links that I need to dynamically import.

This is in Drupal 8 and I have been trying to use the module feeds to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a custom implementation that will dynamically add feed importers based on a particular "Master feed import".

Personally I would do this with the migrate API instead of feeds as it gives you much higher flexibility for data manipulation and queue control for large datasets.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to look into migrate API.

By custom implementation, do you suggest a custom module to handle it through Migrate API?

Comment: @MortenH yes.  When using Migrate, you always have to write a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

If each feed has the same structure, you would only need to create one feed type and then  one feed of that type for each house.

You could write a custom module to dynamically create the feed entities, or to dynamically update them.

Of course, you could also look into Migrate. Migrate does indeed have a larger feature set, but also a steeper learning curve and almost no UI.